# Lookup Name from ID MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I currently use the below Razor syntax to get the name of "Status" from the CaseStatus Table. I use this for a DropDownListFor option in my View. I now want to display the same data but for a Label. Is there a simple way of replicating this for a label?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CaseMaster.CaseStatusId, new SelectList(Model.CaseStatus, "Id", "Name"), "Select Status", new { @class = "form-control col-sm" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just this:

```
<label>@( this.Model.CaseStatus )</label>
```

(Though `<label>` in HTML has a specific purpose for referring to other input elements (that's the `for=""` attribute) or a child input element. If you mean "label" like it was for VB/WPF in that it's a small piece of text displayed on-screen then you can just do `@( this.Model.CaseStatus )` directly.

Comment: I recieve System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Cloak.Models.CaseStatus] when implementing this.

Comment: did you have any other suggestions for me?